# Product images are not showing on front end working fine in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images, frontend

I have created a product and assigned an image to it but on fronend it still showing the demo magento image not mine updated image.

**List.phtml** Image part:

```
   <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">

   <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="img-responsive"/>

   <?php if(basename($_product->getData('image')) != basename($_product->getData('small_image'))): ?>

   <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($size['width'], $size['height']) ?>" 

   alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="img-responsive img-two"/>

             <?php endif ?>

            </a>
```

Admin panel product image: [image]

Front end not showing actual image but the dummy magento image:
[image]

Indexes are updated cache is cleared:
[image]

Comment: try reindexing once from `system > index management`......

Comment: I tried all  these solutions.. not working  @Baby in Magento

Comment: did you checked in product view page ? clearing cache, private window , uploading image to new products?

Comment: yes checked there , created three products but no one is showing the image at all either on category page or details pages @Baby in Magento

Comment: Can you show your `list.phtml`? At least image part?

Comment: Let me show you..

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Please check the updated question.

Comment: Not sure how you getting these- `$size['width'], $size['height']`, can you replace these with some numbers, just to make sure it's not playing the role?

Comment: Actually it is not sourcing the actual image instead its getting the following:
http://mxcounters.com/usa-tiles/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg

Comment: glad that you found solution......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case i have just fixed it by adding echo to my image src so it working now:

```
<?php  echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the size of the image and upload. It is applicable for catalogue section as well.